# Usage of trademarked names in pypi

Tags: trademark

I am not sure if it's the right place to ask, but I don't find better place .

I am holding "`windows`", "apple", "`microsoft`", "`ios`" and lots of other trademarked names on pypi.

**Microsoft** contacted me and asked me to hand over the ownership of those names.  Of course I will do that as they asked me politely.  But they warn me that Microsoft may consider legal action.

My question is,  Is this an obligation?  Can they actually file for open source package names?  And what if I don't want to handover?  (As I said I am just curious about the topic)

ps:  If this question is off topic , please guide me.

Comment: What do you mean by holding names and how do you use them?

Comment: I am using them for distributing some windows related Python packages.

Comment: I think they can't sue you for a registered name if you are using it fairly. for example `for a package named windows for an iot to control your real windows`. Just add a note saying this repo is not related to microsoft windows. Still I am not a lawyer, but just saying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can actually sue you, if that's what you're asking.  You may want to pay a trademark attorney to see if they'll sign a release of liability or the like when you turn the package names over, just to be extra cautious--or to negotiate for a few months to announce to your package users that you are transitioning to new package names.  My guess is they won't bother giving you a release of liability but might be fine with a few months, unless they have a package they want to put out quickly.  That kind of thing is common in Trademark law, and their primary interest is showing that they are protecting their trademark.